# Android Studio Convert ISO string to "America/New_York" when adding to event to calendar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, events, calendar

I am trying to convert a string "2018-10-17T22:00:00Z" to eastern time zone when adding it as an event to a calendar, but instead of it adding the event time as 6pm it is adding it as 10pm.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
String[] segments = uri.getPath().split("/");
Date startDate = null;
Date endDate = null;
Activity activity = (Activity) context;
String stTime = "2018-10-17T22:00:00Z";
String enTime = "2018-10-17T23:00:00Z";
String eventTitle = segments[3];
String eventLocation = segments[4];

TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");

SimpleDateFormat formatStart = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
formatStart.setTimeZone(timezone);

SimpleDateFormat formatEnd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
formatEnd.setTimeZone(timezone);

try {
    startDate = formatStart.parse(stTime);
    endDate = formatEnd.parse(enTime);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Calendar calStart = new GregorianCalendar(timezone);
calStart.setTime(startDate);

Calendar calEnd = new GregorianCalendar(timezone);
calEnd.setTime(endDate);


if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.context, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR},1);
}

Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(calStart.get(Calendar.YEAR), calStart.get(Calendar.MONTH), calStart.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), calStart.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), calStart.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(calEnd.get(Calendar.YEAR), calEnd.get(Calendar.MONTH), calEnd.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), calEnd.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), calEnd.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, beginTime.getTimeInMillis());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endTime.getTimeInMillis());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, eventTitle);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "America/New_York");
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, eventLocation);

cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully Added Event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you're telling the parser to ignore the `Z`, or rather to match it literally, but not to process it's *meaning*.

The input strings are `Instant` values, so parse to `Instant`, *then* apply time zone.
If you don't have Java 8+ compatible Android, use [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP#threeten-android-backport).

```
String stTime = "2018-10-17T22:00:00Z";

ZonedDateTime time = Instant.parse(stTime).atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
System.out.println(time); // prints: 2018-10-17T18:00-04:00[America/New_York]
```

If you prefer using antiquated `SimpleDateFormat`, simply use the correct format, and don't specify time zone.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatStart = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
Date startDate = formatStart.parse(stTime);
// My default time zone is America/New_York, so:
System.out.println(startDate); // prints: Wed Oct 17 18:00:00 EDT 2018
```

`startDate.getTime()` is the time-in-millis you need.

For API Level < 24, format pattern `X` doesn't work, so you need to do the hardcoded `Z` like in your question, but tell the parser that it is in UTC, because that is what the `Z` time zone means.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatStart = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
formatStart.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date startDate = formatStart.parse(stTime);
// My default time zone is America/New_York, so:
System.out.println(startDate); // prints: Wed Oct 17 18:00:00 EDT 2018
```

Comment: when i  use new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"); it throws an error W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'

Comment: @baskin Seems `X` is API Level 24+.

Comment: ok so now i have it adding the right timezone, but i ask this, if i am in California and i add this event it goes in as eastern time 6pm, but reads as 3pm on the calendar, what good does that do if I am planning on attending this event on the east coast?  Is there a way to always display it as EST time?  Thanks for your help

Comment: @baskin What is the time zone of your event calendar?

Comment: I have the emulator default timezone set to Pacific, and the calendar says 3pm, but when you go edit the event it says 6pm ESt

Comment: @baskin Yes, because an event happening at 6 PM EST will happen at 3 PM PST, and your calendar is showing Pacific time. That is correct, because if you're in PST time zone (with your phone) and needs to call in to the event (conference call, web event), then *you* need to do it at 3 PM Pacific time, to see the live event at 6 PM Eastern time.

Comment: basically how can i add the time as EST and have it always display as EST no matter what timezone you are in or travel to.  These are events you attend in person.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181366/discussion-between-baskin-and-andreas).

Comment: @baskin How would the calendar know that? --- Remember, once you fly to Eastern time zone, the calendar will now be Eastern too, and show 6 PM.