# Android change date format from String to Date and Time separated

Tags: java, android, datetime, date-formatting, time-format

I am getting date in this format from API `2019-01-22T04:38:22Z`, which I want it to be separated in date and time with following format `31/01/2019` and `23:59`.

I am new to Java so not able to figure it out how and which class or method I should use to make it. I know little bit bout `SimpleDateFormat`

Any suggestion or idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider not using the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Your original date-time string is in UTC. Do you want the date and time printed in UTC too? For many purposes you would probably prefer the user’s time zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more robust way of accomplishing this task is provided below with a code example.

```
    String initialStringDate = "2019-01-27T09:27:37Z";
    Locale us = new Locale("US");
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", us);
    try {
        Date date = format.parse(initialStringDate);
        String stringDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd", us).format(date);
        String stringTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", us).format(date);

        String finalDateTime = stringDate.concat(" ").concat(stringTime);

        Log.i("Date_and_Time", "" + finalDateTime);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Note: With the provided above code you will be able to even localize your date and time.**

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah, this is better if want to localize the time which is important.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: The answer is not entirely correct. `Z` in the end of the string is an offset and must be parsed as such, or you get the wrong time (on the vast majority of JVMs). Also `new Locale("US")` doesn’t give you what you think (lemme guess, you intended `Locale.US`?)

Comment: @OleV.V. I think you are right but how can I fix this?

Comment: As I may have said, the good fix is using java.time, it has good support for parsing an offset that is given as `Z` when zero. See the linked questions and their answers. [Andreas has a good answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52671099/5772882) showing both the modern and the old-fashioned solutions for Android. If below level 24, there’s no really correct solution using `SimpleDateFormat`; if you still insist on it, the hack is to set the formatter’s time zone to UTC and then parse `Z` as a literal as in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

try this line of code to convert string to date and get date and time

**code**

```
  String dtStart = "2019-01-27T09:27:37Z";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    try {
        Date date = format.parse(dtStart);
        System.out.println(date);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

        String date1 = sdf.format(date);
        String time= sdf1.format(date);
        Log.e("check_date_time",""+date1+"=="+time);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**output**

2019/01/27  09:27

I hope its work for you

Comment: welcome dear... :)

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for your input. I need to check how to use it. BTW, `SimpleDateForat` is not a good idea? If than why?

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is notorious for showing a lot of surprising behaviours including giving wrong results in a lot of situations where one would have expected to be notified of incorrect use. It’s what you’ve got built-in on Android under API level 26, so for simple tasks like this you may weigh the cons against the cons of an external dependency, but generally I recommend you stay away from it. My 0.02.