# How to format current string into a date/time format?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert this String into date/time format
I am getting this string from the database and just want to convert it into proper date and time...
String str = 2019-02-22T13:43:00Z;//input
I am getting proper date from this string by this code:

```
 String[] split_date = date_time.split("T",2);
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 Date   date1  = format.parse ( split_date[0]);
 date_time = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date1);
```

In above code (date_time = 22-Feb-2019 12:00) is coming.
expected output is : 22-feb-2019 13:43
The problem here is I can't get the proper time from that default format.

Comment: What do you mean by proper date ?

Comment: if you want only this "22-Feb-2019" ?

Comment: why are you splitting on `T`?

Comment: I'd look at parsing by using `Instant.parse(date_time)`, and then format to the timezone you need. You can then format to the desired output with any timezone needed. Don't use the old java `Date` classes.

Comment: because of you split `T` take the only first part of it `2019-02-22` and formate with `dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm` you add `hh:mm`. I don't see anywhere in your code you give `hh:mm`. and avoid Date class that is outdated use LocalDate class.

Comment: @SantanuSur Proper time*

Comment: @HiteshTarbundiya i also want time in that, also edited

Comment: @ScaryWombat because there is T between them and atleast i am getting the date by that so...

Comment: @AkashShah if i give hh:mm the exception is coming

Comment: give your simple input and expected output.

Comment: @AkashShah done

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. More details in [the answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55177418/5772882).

Comment: Near-duplicate of [ISO 8601 String to Date/Time object in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941357/iso-8601-string-to-date-time-object-in-android) and [Android Studio Convert ISO string to “America/New_York” when adding to event to calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670961/android-studio-convert-iso-string-to-america-new-york-when-adding-to-event-to) (since `2019-02-22T13:43:00Z` is an ISO 8601 formatted string)

Comment: As @AkashShah correctly states, you are throwing away the `13:43:00` part of the original string, which is why this information is not in your resulting string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2019-02-22T13:43:00Z" ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu HH:mm" ) ;
String output = odt.format( f ) ;
```

output :

```
22-Feb-2019 13:43
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Call requires API level 26 (current min is 19): java.time.Instant#parse

Comment: Not really, @SagarZala. java.time has been backported. Add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your project and use the code in this answer. Just make sure to import from `org.threeten.bp`.

Comment: @SagarZala For Java 6 and 7, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* library. For earlier Android, see the *ThreeTenABP* library.

Comment: Sure. I will see that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
String dt = "2019-02-22T13:43:00Z";
SimpleDateFormat mainformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'", Locale.getDefault());
mainformat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

try {
    Date date1 = mainformat.parse(dt);
    String date_time = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date1);
    Log.e("Date Time", date_time); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> Output: **22-Feb-2019 13:43**

Comment: These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque, Call requires API level 26 (current min is 19): java.time.Instant#parse

Comment: The question states: “expected output is : 22-feb-2019 **13**:43” (my boldfacing). And your parsing is incorrect. `Z` is a UTC offset and must be parsed as such, or you get an incorrect time.

Comment: capital ``HH`` gives 13 instead of 1.

Comment: @AkashShah yes.

Comment: @OleV.V. says it give you an incorrect date when you print `date1` output is in my case `Fri Feb 22 13:43:00 IST 2019` because I am from India `IST`(but time is same) and date is `UTC`. you have to add one more line `mainformat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`

Comment: @SagarZala For Java 6 and 7, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* library. For earlier Android, see the *ThreeTenABP* library.